# C++ Counting different elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to find out how many different elements are in 2 D array. My idea is going through array elements one by one with 2 for loops, then check if element next to is different. If it's true this element will be moved or copied to the new array and in original array will be replaced by (`int`) `0`. And number of elements in new array will raise only if I add different element from others. This is my idea, if someone has better (easier) I will be glad for it.
My current problem is from `std::vector`, I can't convert to `bool`. Or is there better way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int numberofDifferent(int *array[], int lines, int columns)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] != array[i][j+1])
            {
                std::vector<int>n;
                n.push_back(array[i][j]);
                if (bool exist = std::find(std::begin(n), std::end(n), array[i][j]))
                {
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    result++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int a[4][5] = { { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 },
    { 2, 1, 3, 1, 2 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 },
    { 3, 2, 1, 2, 3 } };
    int *array[4] = { a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] };
    printf("number of different elements in array is: %d\n", numberofDifferent(array, 4, 5));  //correct answer: 3
}
```

//sorry for my language

Comment: I'd write an iterator that walks through the array and use that in a call to `std::sort` followed by a call to `std::unique`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an iterator to the found element, not `bool`. It returns iterator to the end of the searched range if nothing was found. So, you'll need a comparison:

```
if(std::find(std::begin(n), std::end(n), array[i][j]) != n.end())
    ...
```

<sup>Removed the unnecessary `bool exists =` part.</sup>

That's just so your code compiles, but the algorithm should be different (for efficiency, I didn't check the validity).

**Edit:**

`std::set` can sort out the duplicates for you, then you just print its size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int a[4][5] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 },
        { 2, 1, 3, 1, 2 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 },
        { 3, 2, 1, 2, 3 }
    };

    std::set<int> set {&a[0][0], &a[3][4]};
    std::cout << "number of unique elements is: " << set.size() << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7850701ca146f64d)

Comment: It was that if line but with bool when I take your current, no errors but it return 0 not 3

Comment: @Mino Edited the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It will take some work to understand it, though. C++'s algorithm library, particularly.

Comment: Going through a `std::vector` is quite roundabout. `std::set` will do all of that work for you automagically. All that code can be reduced to `cout << set<int>{ &a[0][0], &a[3][5] }.size() << endl;`